# Admin on rest - RestClient & Create operation return params + id instead of response.data

Tags: admin-on-rest

In the two REST client (simple & json) provided in the module, on the CREATE operation we have this :

```
case CREATE:
    return { data: { ...params.data, id: json.id } };
```

params is the data sended by the client to the server, json is the data that the server returned.

Why is better to return client data than server response ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the two REST clients, we assume that we can't prejudge what the server will return to us, but the new element's id.
And we're assuming that the data provided for creation will allow the correct display of the list.

But of course, if this is not your case (i.e. you know exactly what the server will return, including some information not requested at creation), you can [decorate an existing client](https://marmelab.com/admin-on-rest/RestClients.html#decorating-your-rest-client-example-of-file-upload) or [create your own](https://marmelab.com/admin-on-rest/RestClients.html#writing-your-own-rest-client).

Comment: I would just add that the other pages will fetch the data from the server anyway after creation. So anything you return from the create action won't be used.

Comment: True, but I tried to use POST request for make actions (i.e the authentification, send POST /auth and receive one access_token)

In this case you can't use only default rest client & CREATE action provided by AOR. That's why I created my own (totally inspired by the existing, I admit)